# Datatable remove rows

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a problem with datatable and jquery.

I have a datatable with buttons and select plugin. I try to add a delete button to delete selected rows.

Here part of my code to init table :

```
        select: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Editer',
                className: 'red',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    dt.ajax.reload();
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Supprimer',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    dt.ajax.reload();
                },
                attr:  {
                    id: 'deleteButton'
                }
            }
       ],
```

And here my function to delete rows :

```
        $(document).on('click', '#deleteButton', function(e){
            var rows = table.rows( '.selected' ).remove().draw(false);
        });
```

But when I select rows and hit delete, rows disappear for 1 seconds then come back.

I tried clear() instead of rows( '.selected' ), but same thing, all rows disappear for 1 secondes then come back.

I use a delete button on each row with :

```
table.row($this.parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
```

And it works well, so why my button doesn't work to remove selected rows ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: It works as expected, you reload the dataset after you have deleted the rows clientside.

Comment: Oooooh common :/ sorry for the noob question